# How to preform REST call to GitLab API from a running job?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I need to make a Gitlab API REST call (let's say "GET /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id") from a script running during CI pipelines' job execution. I need a token to pass through security check. Sure I can create such a token (PAT) and to use it and it works fine. But how can I save/pass this token to the pipeline? To hard-code it in the Gitlab CI YAML file? To hard-code it directly in the script? What is the correct solution here?

I read [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html) that Gitlab itself provides such a token directly in the job. Previously it was stored in the CI_JOB_TOKEN environment variable. I tried it, but I get HTTP 401 error, and it seems its string value is "[MASKED]". How to achieve it - to do REST call with a token during job execution in convenient way? Any example, hints will be very helpful.

EDIT: I found [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gitlab/comments/dhfmzg/how_to_properly_authenticate_to_gitlab_api/f3o872i/). It seems the way is PAT only (separate per project) ?

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I save/pass this token to the pipeline? To hard-code it in the Gitlab CI YAML file? To hard-code it directly in the script? What is the correct solution here?

Just inject it via environment variable: `Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables`